# custom css in admin panel by user id

Tags: css, wp-admin, admin-css

I'm looking for adding a custom css in the admin panel by targeting user id
cause I have another administrator but I want to hide something from him by css.
I'm using this code to put some stylesheet files in the admin panel, but its for all users

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../admincss.css?v=1.3">';
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

done it

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
     global $current_user;
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
if(is_admin() && $user_id == '2'){
    echo '  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../new.css">';
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code into functions.php file. Make sure you are using it right way 
use admin_enqueue_scripts

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'FUNCTION_NAME');function FUNCTION_NAME() {
 global $current_user;
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 if(is_admin() && $user_id == '2'){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
}}
```